# Multi column form field

Tags: forms, symfony

I have googled an found very little. Is there an easy way to specify at the form api level whether a field will render as a single column, or two or more columns?

Do I have to override the individual field templates to achieve this?

Using bootstrap.

Comment: Well... actually, symfony forms does not render fileds as collumns, so what you mean by that? Can you to be a bit more specific? Also, since symfony 2.6 there is a buit-in Bootstrap theme (Zurb Foundation in v2.8): See: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme

Comment: Where I been that I didn't know that the foundation5 template is there! Thanks a lot @felipsmartins

Comment: @malcolm There's a PR and blog post about this: [Blog post](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-form-improvements#foundation-5-form-theme) and [PR #12587](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12587)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in option to display forms in columns. But you can easily pass to each form field a custom CSS class. Something like this:

```
->add('field_name', '...', array(..., 'attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-4 col-md-3')));
```